# Add an "already managed" option for flags for when "helpful" and "declined" don't apply

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Lately, I had some flags declined. I always try to improve my presence here on SO, so i revised what was wrong with my flags. What turned out was that questions or answers i flagged was edited before a moderator could see i flagged it.

So i have both a question and an idea:

1. When revising flagged question or answer, does moderator know on which version i put a flag on?
2. If he/she knows, shouldn't my flag be revised neither as `helpful`, nor as `declined`, but something like `already managed`, if an edit improved what i wanted to tell about?

It wouldn't be so important, but i couldn't use flag functionality for some short period of time because of that couple declined ones, and as long as i can see more and more poor questions it was a bit harmful for me.

Comment: "already managed" seems like a nicer way of telling the user that there are things that can be handled by the community, without having to *decline* flags with the vague message "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"

Comment: This is a really good question.  I sometimes flag posts in other languages for migration with a custom flag.  Those questions often get on-the-spot google translated by editors and boom, flag decline.